# WELD (CDI) + JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cdi, weld

I try to run the example I found in here:
[Using CDI/Weld to Inject JPA/Hibernate Entity Managers](https://www.sitepoint.com/cdi-weld-inject-jpa-hibernate-entity-managers/)

and I get the error:

`WELD-001408:Unsatisfied dependencies for type EntityDao<User> with qualifiers @Named
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Named private com.payby.user.UserIdentityDao.baseEntityDao`

and also I tried to run the example from:
https://bpm.zciok.blog/2017/08/17/hibernate-cdi-example/

but I got the same error. can anyone help me understand why and how I can resolve it.

thanks,
Avner

Comment: please improve your title, it now is just a combination of tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For https://bpm.zciok.blog/2017/08/17/hibernate-cdi-example/ do the following changes in pom.xml, please

add persistence-api dependency

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

remove scope:provided from dependencies to hibernate

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.hibernate}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${version.hibernate}</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```