# Get exact bean via CDI.current().select(Class, Annotation...) with repeatable qualifiers

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, annotations

I cannot get bean what I want, when using CDI and Annotation `@Qualifier`

`@Qualifier @interface` for `Type`

```
@Repeatable(Type.List.class)
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Type {

    String value();

    @Target({TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface List {
        Type[] value();
    }
}
```

and `AnnotationLiteral` implementation

```
public class TypeAL extends AnnotationLiteral<Type> implements Type {

    private final String type;

    public TypeAL(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

`@Qualifier @interface` for `Related`

```
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Related {

    Class value();
}
```

and `AnnotationLiteral` implementation

```
public class RelatedAL extends AnnotationLiteral<Related> implements Related {

    private final Class clazz;

    public RelatedAL(Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Class value() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

When I annotated sth like this:

```
@Type(TYPE_ONE)
@Type(TYPE_TWO)
@Related(RelatedClassWhichWillDoLogic.class)
public class LogicToRelatedClass implements BaseLogic {}
```

and when I'd like to get `CDI.current().select(BaseLogic.class, new TypeAL(TYPE_ONE), new RelatedAL(RelatedClassWhichWillDoLogic.class))` i go nothing...

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

what is the version of your CDI? I think repeating qualifiers has been supported from version 2.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-471
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KUaxXIXJ_r-h5UJGIij6I4vrLS7uXkeeeZr2SaRipWQ/edit#

To choose one implementation between different implementations. we could use qualifier members to narrow the list of possible beans. the injection point must be completely matched with the qualifiers on the bean(if you want the exact one). you have two Type annotations on your bean class but use one of them in your CDI.current().select method call.

```
Instance<BaseLogic> findedBeans = CDI.current().select(BaseLogic.class, new TypeAL("TYPE_ONE"), new TypeAL("TYPE_TWO"), new RelatedAL(RelatedClassWhichWillDoLogic.class));
```

I tested it In one Weld Java SE program. you can download it from [WELD (CDI) + JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038362/weld-cdi-jpa/53038881#53038881)

just in the main method, in App class, add the following line of the code.

```
UserApplication userApplication = container.instance()
                .select(UserApplication.class)
                .get();
        Instance<BaseLogic> type_one = CDI.current().select(BaseLogic.class, new TypeAL("TYPE_ONE"), new TypeAL("TYPE_TWO"), new RelatedAL(RelatedClassWhichWillDoLogic.class));
```

[image]

Comment: I need to get this class based on `BaseLogic.class`, `new TypeAL("TYPE_ONE")` and `RelatedClassWhichWillDoLogic.class`, but I can have got another `TypeAL` annotations

Comment: did you run the example that is mentioned in the answer? it worked. in select, you specify at least requirement for bean selection and it is possible that it returns more than on bean(all the beans that satisfy the type and qualifiers)